# verification of continuity $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ for $f(x,y) = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

$$
 f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}   & \text{if $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ } \\[2ex]
0 & \text{if $(x,y)=(0,0)$ }  \\
\end{cases}
$$

we have to verify whether  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$ or not.

---

My answer :

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\operatorname{sgn}(y)$

hence,   $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ should not be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Unfortunately, I did not get answers to verify it myself.

Thank You.

Comment: How did you arrive at this answer? Can you add your work to the post? Maybe in this way, a user can help you more precisely.

Comment: @ A.P. I used [this](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=f772ef284975314fJmltdHM9MTY3MTIzNTIwMCZpZ3VpZD0xNTM2YTNlZi03MThjLTZlZGUtMWE0YS1hYzI3NzA5YTZmN2UmaW5zaWQ9NTYyOQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=1536a3ef-718c-6ede-1a4a-ac27709a6f7e&u=a1L3ZpZGVvcy9zZWFyY2g_cT1wYXJ0aWFsK2Rlcml2YXRpdmUrbGltaXQmdmlldz1kZXRhaWwmbWlkPUYyMkQyRjI5MkM2MEY4NzhENzM1RjIyRDJGMjkyQzYwRjg3OEQ3MzUmRk9STT1WSVJF&ntb=1)  to find it. It would take long time to type the code for same (because I'm not used to it).

Comment: @CaptainPotato Not to sound rude but you are at the same time , expecting the users of this site to write answers to help you but you yourself are reluctant to type in the code because it would take "long time"? . What about the time and effort of the person who answers your question? . Is it in someway less valuable than yours?

Comment: @CaptainPotato: You don't need to use so much mathematical symbolism to write how you arrived at that answer. You can use a lot of words to explain how you arrived at the answer, something like: "using the definition of continuity applied to the function f_x I get this expression P(x,y) and then simplifying I get this answer". The important thing is that you show your effort and we will surely consider that to give a better answer that is useful to you.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron I don't know how to write the code. so, i will have to learn it first then write it. The code I used for the question is copied from some other question. Sorry for the inconvenience. I assure you that i didn't mean to devalue your time.

Comment: by the way, @CaptainPotato, irrelevant question and most probably an incorrect guess, but are you from IITKGP?

Comment: @insipidintegrator yes [and clearly you too are from]  and how is my answer is wrong

Comment: @CaptainPotato You have not calculated the partial derivative properly. To put it in plain terms , treat $y$ as a constant and differentiate with respect to $x$. Mind you that you are not asked to compute the partial derivative at $(0,0)$ which is just $0$ and can be easily done using the definition using limits. But you are asked to check the continuity of the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ . If by IITKGP you mean IIT Kharagpur(just a guess as Sundar Pichai is from there) , then it's a fine institution and you should be able to calculate partial derivatives at this level.

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron actually i did the same way but in the last part of  i substituted x=$0$ which gives $y^3\over |y^3|$ which is sign(y) and sign(y) is discontinuous at y=$0$.

Comment: After you have calculated the partial derivative, substituting $x=0$ means you are approaching the origin only through the $y$ axis. So proving "discontinuity of the function restricted to the $y$ axis is not enough". You have to show that the limit does not exist. One way to show that is to show that it is not unique and hence cannot exist.  That is in your method for example, you show that the limit when approached from the top (i.e. y$\geq 0$ , you get limit as $+1$ and when approaced from below you get $-1$.

Comment: So claiming that the "partial derivative" is itself $sign(y)$ is incorrect. The partial derivative at points other than the origin is $\frac{y^{3}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$ . And at the origin it is $\lim_{k\to 0}\frac{f(0,0+k)-f(0,0)}{k} = \lim_{k\to 0}\frac{0}{k} = 0$ . If $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ was continuous in a neighbourhood of the origin, then you could get the explicit value of the partial derivative at a particular point by just evaluating the expression at that point. Here you cannot do that as it is not continuous.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\begin{cases} \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}}-\frac{x^{2}y}{(\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}})^{3}}=\frac{(x^{2}+y^{2})y-x^{2}y}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}=\frac{y^{3}}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,\,,(x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0 \, ,(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

To disprove continuity at $(x,y)=(0,0)$ you can take the line $y=mx$ and you get

$$\frac{m^{3}x^{3}}{(1+m^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}x^{3}}=\frac{m^{3}}{(1+m^{2})^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ which clearly gives different values for different values of $m$. Hence the limit cannot be unique. So it cannot exist